# Payment button position

Tags: ux-designer, billing, crm

I am working on CRM system design. Recently working on billing page. I want to know that which is better for users. check below screenshot

Sample 1 
[image]

Full Page View

[image]

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, without seeing the wider context.

Comment: @MattObee Edited

Comment: Why is the amount separated?

Comment: Why not just A/B test both and then understand what _your_ users want?

Comment: @Majo0od there is only one plan. In first panel there is only information about customer. when user click on pay now then they will redirect to paypal for payment.

Comment: @NewAlexandria there are no customers right now. its startup. is there any other suggestions for A/B testing?

Comment: Even at this stage, if "there are no customer" then you are not validating your product in a Lean way, and you increase your risk of failing & having wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second button position looks better. The first one looks like an old 1999 design: Centering and stacking.

You could think about the text `$200 - Business Plan` being all the way left and the button all the way to the right.

---

Something else to say for your conversion rate: Minimize the feel of loosing money for the user. Use something like `check out` instead of `pay now`. Make the number smaller. You could display `Business Plan` first in normal font and color and below display the price small and gray.

This should boost your conversion rate later. You maybe even want to read this outstanding [guide on how to format money](https://www.nickkolenda.com/psychological-pricing-strategies/) to make the user buy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screen shot it looks fine. But if that button sits at the bottom of a very long page are you sure there is enough direction it. Are you confident the user will know to scroll to the bottom of the page to click?

Comment: Eh? Of course they will scroll down. I've worked on far too many ecommerce sites to know that this page is necessary to drive to that button (they have to confirm that their information is correct before moving forward). That's not the issue in my opinion.

Comment: Well unless you state what you are actually trying to figure out, we are in the dark. There is a price next to a pay now button. The pay now button will trigger the purchase. That is completel normal and well understood.

Comment: @BrianMccann There is no scroll bar in this screen. so user will see pay now button in first view. My question is which position is good for users. at bottom or top of the page?